# jQuery Validation conditional rule makes input never valid - valid always returns 0

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm having a problem with jQuery validation conditional rules.

I specify a conditional rule for an element as such:

```
var validatorSettings = $("form").data('validator').settings; 
validatorSettings.rules = $.extend({}, validatorSettings.rules, {
        TimeFrameAmount: {
            number: function() { return $("select[name='TimeFrameUnits']").val() === "true"; },
            required: function() { return $("select[name='TimeFrameUnits']").val() === "true" } ;
        }
});
```

Problem is when I submit the form, `$("form").valid()` returns 0.

I traced is down to see that `$("input[name='TimeFrameAmount']").valid()` is the only element in the form that returns 0 and thus is the element causing the form to fail validation.

I further traced this down that `$("input[name='TimeFrameAmount']").valid()` **always** returns 0 and causes the form to fail validation even if the conditional rule functions both return false.

I checked this by setting a break point in the conditional rule functions, then triggered a call to `$("input[name='TimeFrameAmount']").valid()` from the Firefox console.

My conditional rules both return false and `$("input[name='TimeFrameAmount']").valid()` still returns 0 and the form fails validation.

One thing to note is that the `errorPlacement` callback in not fired when my conditional rules return false, which makes sense since no validation = no errors.

In fact, the input even has the "valid" class at the time I validate the form (and still has it after)

However, neither of those things prevent the `valid()` method from returning that 0

Any ideas how to get the form to pass validation?

Comment: Which validation plugin is this? The rules look rather odd.

Comment: jQuery validate. Please see the comment in kjetilh's answer. Can you confirm if those functions are for the rule logic or rule conditionality

Comment: You mean http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate ? I get half a million results for "jquery validate" Google search...

Comment: Please be more careful when tagging.  `[jquery-validate]` and `[jquery-validation-engine]` are two totally different plugins.

Comment: Sorry, didn't know that. Will keep in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the correct syntax to add conditional rules are:

```
TimeFrameAmount: { 
    required: { 
        depends : function () { 
            //check conditionality 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood, those functions specific WHEN to evaluate the rule, if they return false then the "required" rule registered in the validator will not execute. It is not supposed to define the actual rule... that is registered with the validator using addMethod(). That is the way I understand it and believe that to be the case. The "true" is an actual value of an option in a selectbox that will make the input in question required, it could also be "yes" or anything else. In other word when "TimeFrameUnits" is "true", then "TimeFrameAmount" becomes required.

Comment: Ah I see. I must have misunderstood. You should include a link to the plugin you're using

Comment: Turns out we both misunderstood. The correct syntax is TimeFrameAmount: { required : { depends : function () { //check conditionality  } } } . Please edit your answer and I'll mark. Thanks